# How to change the title of a Word file using PHPWord TemplateProcessor

Tags: php, phpword

I am trying to create one .docx file from a template using the below code.

```
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor(storage_path().'\app\public\sample\sample.docx');
$phpWord->setValue('days', '365');
$phpWord->setValue('what', 'Benchmark');
$phpWord->setValue('test', 'KKKK');
$phpWord->setValue('best', 'MMMM');
$phpWord->saveAs(storage_path().'\app\public\sample\final.docx');
```

the sample.docs file is like.

[image]

but when I run the above code the generated final.docx is like this.

[image]

**test** and **best** variables are updated but **days** and **what** are not updated. **days** and **what** are in the title of .docx document. but I am not aware of how to update it using PHPWord

The example sample.doc file link is [here](https://easyupload.io/enly10)

Comment: You should provide the sample.docx file.

Comment: Docx documents are XML. PHPWord performs search & replace within the raw XML content. Therefore, you should make sure that your template does not contain invisible XML tags between your variables: `<w:t>Microsoft ${</w:t><w:t>days}</w:t>` will not work because the variable is split in 2 XML tags.

Comment: The fact that the variables are in the title has likely nothing to do with the capability of replacing the variables. Something else is the culprit, but we can only investigate further if you provide the .docx file.

Comment: @Olivier, I have added a link of my .docx file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## **Reformat the document...**

The template you've provided has a "content control" in the title which seems to be incompatible with the library or code. Highlight the title and **remove the content control** like so:
[image: remove the content control]

## **..and voila** !

No major changes are required for the code. I have rewritten it for simplicity.

```
$in = storage_path()."\app\public\sample\sample.docx";
$out = storage_path().'\app\public\sample\final.docx';

$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor($in);

$templateVars = [
  'days'=>'365',
  'what'=>'Benchmark',
  'test'=>'KKKK',
  'best'=> 'MMMM'
];

$phpWord->setValues($templateVars);

$phpWord->saveAs($out);
```

Answer (score 0):

try to replace the whole title block with a configured title, by using the replaceBlock function. In order to do it, u need to declare a block like this in your word file:

```word
${block_name}
The text you want to replace.
${/block_name}
```

To replace the block with another one implement this line of code into your PHP:

```html
$phpWord->replaceBlock('block_name', "CIS Microsoft {$days} Foundations {$what}");
```

not the cleanest solution but better than nothing. Hope I could help ^^

Side note:

your can change multiple values by using:

```html
$phpWord->setValues(array('test' => 'KKKK', 'best' => 'MMMM'));
```

Comment: It is also not replacing the block in the title.